# how to use dynamic variable for symbols in ruby where statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I dont how to accomplish this problem.

I faced with this problem 3 times and each time I put it in my todo list but even tho I tried to find a solution I couldnt.

For examples,

I m trying to create a query with dynamic variables of this example;

User.search(first_name_start: 'K')

there are 3 arguments in this example;

1)first_name - My model attribute
2)start - Query type (start/end/cont ) 
3)'3'  - value

I was able to create dynamic ActiveRecord using static symbols but how am I suppose to make dynamic input

Thanks in advance

EDIT: ADDITIONAL INFORMATION

let me show you a some kind of pseudo-code

```
    varArray.each_with_index |x,index|

    queryString=varArray[i]+"_"+filterArray=[i] #lets say varArray[i], this will be first_name, an actual model attribute/a column in my db 
#and filterArray like /start/end/with a filter type
#and finally valArray a string value like  'geo' or 'paul'
User.where(queryString valArray[i]).result
```

I tried to use send(variable) but that didnt help me either, so i dont how should i proceed,

Comment: @D-side, what do you mean by conditions on columns? I have everything what i need, I'm getting my User model columns as first argument, and a filter type like ends with, starts with as second argument, and finally a value to search for as final argument

Comment: ".to_sym didnt help me," -- please be more specific.

Comment: The question is a bit hard to understand, sorry. You want to pass in a symbol from a variable, right?

Comment: @D-side not quite, let me edit my question and explain a bit more

Comment: ...and compose the symbol from strings you already have. If that's the case, I'm ready to hit "Answer".

Comment: @D-side can you read the edit pls, i think your answer would hit the spot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of a few cases where new fancy Ruby 1.9 syntax for defining hashes doesn't cut it. You have to use the traditional hashrocket (`=>`) that allows you to specify not only symbols, but any arbitrary values as hash keys:

```
column = "#{first_name}_size_#{query_type}".to_sym
User.where( column => value )
```

AFAIK, ActiveRecord is able to accept strings instead of symbols as column names, so you don't even need to call `to_sym`.

Comment: @iosMessenger a humble recommendation: you could use some plain Ruby knowledge, I suggest you read "Beginning Ruby". I've read it after Rails Tutorial, seems odd, but works okay.

Comment: I'm very well aware of that, i'm really not well educated in basic concepts, do you have any source to read and make my self knowledgable

Comment: @iosMessenger I accidentally hit "Post" in the middle of suggesting one. Damn touchscreens :) "Beginning Ruby", published by Apress. I read 2nd edition.